# How to set online pin verification in EMV

Tags: payment, emv

I'm trying to modify terminal capabilities to accept just online Card PIN verification here is an example that work with offline:

```
tag ="x9F\x33" value="xE0\xF8\xC8"
```

1.Now I need to change the value to force terminal accept just online PIN verification

2.I'm looking for tool that helps me to generate these tags and values for EMV

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware of a (free) tool that generates tags value for you. 
Commercial sniffer tools (like [Fime smartSpy](https://www.fime.com/smartspy-contact.html)) may help you by analyzing the transaction and decomposing each tag.

However, the following web sites may help you find the proper documentation for each tag :

- http://www.emvlab.org/emvtags/
- https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/145-emv-nfc-tags

@arved is right, the details for tag 9F33 (Terminal Capabilities) are to be found in Annex "A2 Terminal Capabilities" of [EMV book 4](https://www.emvco.com/download_agreement.aspx?id=655).

The terminal Cardholder Verification Methods (CVM) are defined in byte 2 of terminal capabilities. If you just want "enciphered PIN for online verification", byte 2 should be set to 0x40.

**So, tag 0x9F33 should bet set to 0xE040C8**